# I need the complete list of date format in meteor autoform

Tags: date-formatting, meteor-autoform

I am trying to bring up a date format of "Monday, February 2,2015" in meteor autoform, from this code

```
moment.utc("2015-02-02").format("LL")
```

I would like to have a list like in php.date function shows the full date format.

I believe each one of us will find few and post here so that we get the complete list. I googled and I never got the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but this might help.
http://momentjs.com/